# PHP date reshaping

Tags: php, date

This is supposed to take a date that is currently in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`  and convert it to d M Y. Instead it gives me 1 Jan 1970 which clearly means it does not like the timestamp

```
<?php $cdate = $comment->comment_date; echo date('d M Y', $cdate);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo date('d M Y', strtotime($cdate));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$cdate = strtotime($comment->comment_date); 
echo date('d M Y', $cdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function date expect a UNIX time stamp as the 2nd parameter, that's why you need to convert your MySQL like time stamp to a UNIX time stamp using strtotime.

```
echo date('d M Y', strtotime($comment->comment_date);
```